# s’attendre ou non, se sourire sans plus, ne pas se voir

Tags: grammaire

In the quote below, the infinitive forms of the verbs in bold seem to suggest that the meaning is "**ce qu'elles doivent s'attendre, se sourire, etc.**", which to me seems strange and ungrammatical. Please explain.

> Toutes savent d’instinct ce qu’elles doivent faire quand elles se croisent près du lycée, **s’attendre** ou non, **se sourire** sans plus, **ne pas se voir**. (*Les Années*, Annie Ernaux, pages 76-77)

Comment: It seems to me that an almost word for word translation into English conveys the correct meaning. “Everybody instinctually knows what they should do — to wait or not, to smile without (doing) more, to not notice each other.” Could you clarify what you’re having a problem understanding?

Comment: "_ce qu'elles doivent s'attendre_" doesn't work in French. "_ce *à quoi* elles doivent s'attendre_", because _on s'attend à quelque chose_. Note that _elles savent ce qu'elles doivent faire_ is correct, because _savoir_ wants a COD.

Answer (score 4):

The verb groups *s’attendre ou non*, *se sourire sans plus*, *ne pas se voir* develop *ce qu'elles doivent faire*.

Toutes savent:

- si elles doivent s'attendre ou non
- si elles doivent se sourire sans plus
- si elles doivent ne pas se voir.

So another way to write the sentence could be:

> Toutes savent d'instinct quand elles se croisent près du lycée si elles doivent s'attendre ou non, se sourire sans plus, ne pas se voir.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you all.  Perhaps then the infinitives suggest "Toutes savent s’attendre ou non, se sourire sans plus, ne pas se voir"?  A colon in that case instead of a comma would have made it easier.  Thanks again.  --- tk

Comment: @tk a colon would definitely be preferred in a non-literary context. In literature both can be used (also a dash). The choice of a comma is more about the way you read/scan the text. It's a shorter pause than a colon and makes for a faster rythm.